# Flutter Linux app build failed due to unrecognize gtk3 installation in ArchLinux

Tags: flutter, cmake, archlinux

I tried to build flutter Linux desktop app in Arch Linux and it raise a error with a following error msg.

```
[  +41 ms] -- Checking for module 'gtk+-3.0'
[   +6 ms] --   Package 'gtk+-3.0', required by 'virtual:world', not found
[        ] CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:562
(message):
[   +2 ms]   A required package was not found
[        ] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[        ]   /usr/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:784
(_pkg_check_modules_internal)
[        ]   flutter/CMakeLists.txt:24 (pkg_check_modules)
```

I've checked output of `flutter doctor -v` it said:

```
✗ GTK 3.0 development libraries are required for Linux development.
      They are likely available from your distribution (e.g.: apt install libgtk-3-dev)
```

I already have installed a `gtk3` Arch Linux package,
But flutter does not recognize it.

Why flutter is not able to found gtk3?

---

#### Update:

Result of pacman -Ql gtk3 is that shows very long list of files which installed by the package. (I can not paste it because too long so it exceed limitation of number of characters)

`pkg-config --exists gtk3` has returned `0`, And `gtk+-3.0.pc` does exists in `/usr/lib/pkgconfig`

---

My versions are:

```
Flutter 2.5.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 18116933e7 (4 weeks ago) • 2021-10-15 10:46:35 -0700
Engine • revision d3ea636dc5
Tools • Dart 2.14.4
```

Comment: Please, add to the question post the line **above** the line `CMake Error`. Exactly that line notes the name of the missed package. If you want to debug why CMake doesn't the package, then you could start with running in command line `pkg-config gtk3`: exactly `pkg-config` tool is used by `pkg_check_modules` CMake function.

Comment: I added verbose `flutter run` log 
And there is nothing output of `pkg-config gtk3`.

Comment: pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0

Comment: pacman -Ql gtk3

Comment: pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0 output is
```Package gtk+-3.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk+-3.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'gtk+-3.0', required by 'virtual:world', not found
```

Comment: result of packan -Ql gtk3:
https://gist.github.com/KiYugadgeter/c5f6fb18a1bdf8141be0daed2455e574

Comment: gtk+-3.0.pc does exists in /usr/lib/pkgconfig(default search location of pkg-config) so I have no idea why flutter does not recognize it.

Comment: Uninstall Homebrew (brute force solution...)